# Lisp: How to prompt-read a float?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, slime

I have a function where I am using parse-integer and prompt-read together. However, I need one of these integers to be a float. When I change parse-integer to parse-float it no longer works.
Here is the function:

```
(defun prompt-for-cat ()                                                       
  (add-record                                                                  
    (make-cat                                                                    
      (prompt-read "Name")                                                        
      (prompt-read "Coloring")                                                    
      (or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Weight") :junk-allowed t) 0)               
      (or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Experience") :junk-allowed t) 0)           
      (or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Length") :junk-allowed t) 0))))
```

This works as is, but I need that first integer, "Weight" to be a float. parse-float does not work and I cannot find the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(let ((weight (progn
                (format t "Weight: ")
                (read t))))
  (if (floatp weight) weight 0))
```

Comment: I guess I should be more clear. I've been learning Lisp for a little over 2 weeks so I'm very new. I do not understand this.
I also need to use that "prompt-read" function in the same way I used it in the rest of that function. So if you assumed I'd know how to do that, that's my fault, but I do not.

Comment: Looks to work as is. I guess can learn how it works from my professor. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how the function prompt-read works, so I use format instead. In particular, how it stores the entered values. Normally it's bad style -and dangerous- to use global variables, which seems to be what it's doing. That's where the LET comes into play. But the important thing for you is to replace prompt-read with READ, which can read and parse a float.

Comment: Note that for improved portability, one needs to call `(finish-output)`, since output streams can be buffered.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS in any production code.  If you use `READ` without very careful controls around it then someone typing at the prompt can make the Lisp do *anything*.  This is the equivalent of allowing an SQL injection attack, except that the language standard is the documentation on how to do the attack.

Answer (score 4):

There are two approaches to doing this.  One is to use `read` in some form, and the other one is to use a float-parsing library.

### Using `read`

Using `read` is fraught with danger, to put it mildly.  In particular you are open to code injection attacks unless you are careful.  **Never use `read` in code where you do not fully trust the input**, unless you have, at least, wrapped some safety precautions around it.

That said, here is a function which tries to use `read` in a minimally safe way to read a float with a prompt.

```
(defun prompt-for-float (prompt &optional (default 0.0))
  ;; Use READ to read a float, in a way which should be at least
  ;; minimally safe.
  (with-standard-io-syntax
    (let ((*read-eval* nil))
      (format *query-io* "~A: " prompt)
      (finish-output *query-io*)
      (let ((result (read *query-io*)))
        (typecase result
          (float result)
          (real (coerce result 'float))
          (t default))))))
```

This at least *tries* to be safer by standardising the syntax, and turning off read-time evaluation, which is how code injection attacks happen.

However this may still not be completely safe.  As well as possibly not being safe, in the sense of allowing the execution of uncontrolled code on the system, using `read` without a heavily-constrained readtable also is not side-effect free (it can intern symbols, for instance), and can allow various possible denial-of-service attacks, for instance by causing a large amount of memory allocation.  To deal with those problems you either need to do a lot of work cutting the readtable down to something which is safe, or use a library which just reads the type or types you care about.

### Using a float-parsing library

There is a library called [parse-float](https://github.com/soemraws/parse-float) which solves this problem for you.  This library is available via [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).  Assuming you have Quicklisp installed (which you should have: if not, then your first problem is arranging for that to be true), then using is it is as simple as saying `(ql:quickload "parse-float")`, and then parsing the float with, for instance:

```
> (parse-float:parse-float "12.2")
12.2
4
```

Comment: as for examples of why `prompt-for-float` may still be unsafe: the readtable allows short syntax for things that might allocate a lot, like `#500000000000*0`, but also circular structures (the amusing `#1A#1=(0 . #1#)` array) or even div by zero errors at read-time `5/0`. Also, `read` might intern symbols (pollution), etc. The good news is that a counter-measure is possible: the programmer needs to restrict the readtable significantly and catch errors.

Comment: @coredump: yes, I've added some notes about that sort of thing.  An interesting approach would be to try to come up with something which would both raise an exception at read-time *and* leave circular structure on the stack which could then cause entertainment if you ended up in the debugger.  Somewhere I have a constrained-read thing I wrote which tried to tie down the readtable far enough to be safe.